# host not found in upstream "php-fpm" in /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample

Tags: php, nginx, magento, fpm

facing the issue when try to install the magento on linux. when i run the ngnix -t command is show the error.

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php-fpm" in /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample:50

```js
# file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento.conf

upstream fastcgi_backend {
server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {
server_name magento2.com;
listen 80;
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;
set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

access_log /var/log/nginx/magento-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/magento-error.log;

include /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Comment: Can you up file /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample in your question so we can check it?